# Как управлять видимостью курсора в EditText?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, курсор

В приложении под Android (kotlin) в одном из фрагментов у меня есть EditText. При переходе на экран этого фрагмента в поле EditText курсора не видно. При нажатии на поле появляется клавиатура, мигает курсор, я ввожу какой-то текст и после того, как клавиатура скрывается, в поле постоянно продолжает мигать курсор после введённого текста. Вопрос состоит в том, как скрыть курсор после того, как скроется клавиатура?

Comment: editText.clearFocus()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582702/disable-edittext-blinking-cursor

Answer (score 1):

Я бы написал, что то типа:

```
  txtEdit.setOnFocusChangeListener(object:OnFocusChangeListener() {
    fun onFocusChange(v:View, hasFocus:Boolean) {
         txtEdit.setCursorVisible(hasFocus)
  }})
```

Смысл в том, что при потере фокуса в `EditText` - скрываем курсор, а при появлении фокуса его показываем.

P.S. Не тестировал.

**Update**

Попробуйте так:

```
txtEdit.post(() -> {
    txtEdit.setCursorVisible(hasFocus);
    })
```

Comment: может так будет красивее -  `txtEdit.setCursorVisible(hasFocus)` чисто как вариант :)

Comment: Точно! Сейчас исправлю

Comment: Смысл понятен, но курсор продолжает предательски моргать) Но всё равно спасибо!

Comment: посмотрите на апдейт

Comment: Вот что пишет: 
Expecting ')'
Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Comment: Написано на Java - переведите на Kotlin